# how to store data retrieved from database into a variable so that I can avoid hitting database again

Tags: java, jdbc, static, static-methods

I have a webapp where I need to retrieve data from DB via JDBC and display it front end. Its a static data and it wont be changed. So I just need the data to be retrieved just once and store in a static variable and so I can use that data every time instead of querying the database. Below is the sample code:

```
 public class SampleClass(){
    static Map<String, BigDecimal> productMap = null;

    public Map<String, BigDecimal> getDatafromDB(Connection conn, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

        if(productMap == null){

          productMap = getProductID(conn, stmt, rs);
        }

        return productMap;
        }

public Map<String, BigDecimal> getProductID(Connection conn, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        logger.debug("retrieving product ID's from product table..");
        Map<String, BigDecimal> productMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from PRODUCTTABLE");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        logger.debug("Product ID's retrieved");
        while(rs.next()){

            productMap.put(rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME"),rs.getBigDecimal("PRODUCT_ID"));
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }

        return productMap;
    }

    }
```

I am calling this method from UI through a http servlet request. For the first time when I run it, since the map is null it queries the data base and gets the data and sends it to UI. When I hit the servlet again for the second time with the new request the product map is null and again its querying the database and getting the data. Since its a static variable it should be only initialized once rite so why is it still null for the second request. Can someone please correct my code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show us `retreivedatafromDB()` method

Comment: And what if someone else updates the database between your method calls? Caching some database data doesn't really make sense

Comment: Caching is a technique that you might have to use and also think of having a static initializer instead if you want to fill that static map of yours! The class should be loaded only once!

Comment: The product table will not be updated by anyone else since its a master table and the changes into that table will happen only when there is a new product launched. For each application form which is submitted in UI, we need to retrieve the products from Database and compare with the product which the user has submitted and store that related product ID in a different table. For that I need to hit the DB and get the products eveytime when an application form is submitted in front end. So since the data is static i.e. preloded into DB, how to avoid hitting DB multiple times ?

Comment: Also when we add a new product to DB, then we will be stopping the servers and get the DB updated and then we will restart the app servers. I am not sure whether this is a good approach or not

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is that a servlet is memoryless. So a static variable will not help. What you need is a session attribute instead.

I suggest adding your variable as a session attribute. In the first place you need to create an encapsulating class that implements Serializable:

```
public class SampleResult implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, String> productMap;

    public void setProductMap(Map<String, String> productMap) {
        this.productMap = productMap;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProductMap() {
        return productMap;
    }
}
```

Now in your servlet:

```
HttpSesssion session = request.getSession();

Map<String, String> productMap;
SampleResult result;

if (session.getAttribute("productMap") == null) {
    productMap = retrievedatafromDB();
    result = new SampleResult();
    sampleResult.setProductMap(productMap);
    session.setAttribute("productMap", result);// session attribute created
} else {
    result = session.getAttribute("productMap");// retrieve session attribute
    productMap = result.getProductMap();
}
```

Comment: This is only useful if that product map is to user/session specific. My guess would be that the OP wants that product map to be application scope, not session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as Mark said I want the product map to be application scope not the session scope.